# SOAPUI: validation XML response against xsd schema fails

Tags: soapui, xsd-validation, assertion

It looks like xsd:any is not recognized by SoapUI(5.4.0) schema compliance assertion.
I have the following xsd definition:

```
<xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="FailureResponse" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="ObjectList" type="mp:ObjectListType" />
</xs:choice>
<xs:complexType name="ObjectListType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="count" type="xs:int" />
</xs:complexType>
```

When response with "YYY" list that is part of ObjectList arrives , the following assertion is thrown:
Schema compliance failed:
Element not allowed: YYY element in element ObjectList

The response looks like:

```
<mp:ObjectList count="1">
        <mp:YYY>
           ...
        </mp:YYY>
 </mp:ObjectList>
```

Any ideas how to fix or known issues about?

Comment: Just a short guess: maybe you should ous xs:all instead of a sequence, since you want to put anything in there as it seems.